# Spacing width between lines

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a textbox which has text that is coming from a stored procedure. I'm trying to increase the line spacing between text so that the text doesn't seem so "squished together".

i.e.
ABC
DEF

I want slightly more spacing between ABC and DEF. Using the newline operation isn't feasible, because the spacing will be too large.

I've tried using the line spacing property option but that hasn't made a difference.

Edit: DEF should be directly under ABC in the example.

Comment: What kind of programming language do you use?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "line spacing", not "word spacing"?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is unfortunately not possible in SSRS. From the [relevant documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx), here's the limited list of what you can do with CSS in reports:

> - text-align, text-indent
> - font-family
> - font-size [...] Supported units are: in, cm, mm, pt, pc. [...]
> - color
> - padding, padding-bottom, padding-top, padding-right, padding-left
> - font-weight

Your question speaks of "line spacing" (i.e. [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)?), but your examples seem to be about [word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing). Unfortunately, neither's available in SSRS.

For word-spacing I can only think of hacks and workarounds, most of which aren't pretty:

- Use SQL or expressions to double spaces, e.g. `Replace(Fields!Xyz.Value, " ", "  ")`
- Choose a different font that allows for more space between words.

Beyond that workarounds get even less pretty.

For word-spacing I can't really think of any workarounds, except for the one you used (linebreaks) or using a different font.

Bottom line is probably that you can't really do anything about his, AFAIK.

Comment: I actually had the two words on separate lines when I initially posted it, but the words automatically got put onto the same line. But yes, I am talking about line spacing.

Comment: Fair enough. I slightly updated my answer, but the bottom line remains unchanged unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to control this by double spacing my text and then changing the font size of the second line break

For example:

```
text <--CRLF, 8pt  
<-- CRLF, 4pt  
text
```

It's not very scalable, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding padding in the textbox and changing the vertical alignment. It will increase the space between the cells. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but you can do that by changing SpaceAfter and SpaceBefore properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`TextBox Properties -> Font -> Line Spacing -> Custom`

**UPDATE**:

This is Microsoft bug..

The line spacing depends on font size... option below doesn't work..

Comment: That's the property that I was using but didn't work. I'm also exporting to PDF as well.

Comment: That's also what I read. However, setting the property didn't make a difference for the HTML rendering on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a line any height you want. When you select the line on the far left side of the row drag your mouse to increase the row height. Set the vertical alignment in the text box to Top.  This will stop the data from moving to the center of the box or you can use padding options for the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to natively do this, but a very customisable way is to simply add lines in between your lines manually and change the font-size so that the line size decreases respectively. A bit time-consuming but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that if I add blank expressions within my text I can trick SSRS to double space.

```
right click-> Create Placeholder 
Do this mid sentence on the second or subsequent line
Set the Value in Placeholder Properties to ="" (*an empty string*)
```

you will have text in your SSRS document that looks like this:

```
I want to <Expr>double space.
Now highlight the <Expr> and set the text size to double the font you're using
```

And the report will render with the effect of double spacing.